# Is there a way to incorporate versioning for training phrases in Dialogflow

Tags: google-cloud-platform, nlp, dialogflow-es

Dialogflow has a Versions and Environments BETA. I understand that creating a version captures the current state of your agent. I would like to know if this includes training phrases? When I tried to revert to a different version it did not rollback the changes changes to the training phrases

Secondly, if anyone can answer this question - what is the point of creating a version without publishing?

Answer (score 0):

Quoting the [docs](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/agents-versions):

> A version is an immutable copy of the current state of your agent, which you can then publish to an environment. When a new version is created, a snapshot of the **intents and entities** in your current agent is used.

So it should work, but you would also have to publish an environment. Please note that this is currently a beta feature, so it might have some issues.

Personally I am using option to export agent data to zip file through API and version through this data in a separate repository.